# Passing Extras to DroidReader

Tags: android, pdf

I want to show single page (Fit by width) of my PDF file in the DroidReader. I've Googled about it but found no solution. Please guide me about any parameter or putExtra kinda thing which can be pass to DroidReader to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [home page of that project](http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/) provides instructions on how to get help with that project.

There does not appear to be an extra that does what you seek, but you are better off following their instructions to get help.