# Starting a specific app in Android

Tags: android, pdf, pdfview

I know how to load a PDF file in Android. But if more than one PDF viewers are installed, Android shows a list to choose from. I want to load my PDF file with a specific PDF viewer (say DroidReader). How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then specify the complete name of the activity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.package.name.of.droidreader", "com.package.name.of.droidreader.DroidReader");
    intent.setComponent(comp);
    startActivity(intent);
```

To know what the package name and activity are, you could take a look at the `adb logcat` output: when you open an activity it gets logged there. And, of course, configure the intent correctly so that the DroidReader know what file to open.

Lastly, but important, you should surround the `startActivity` method with a `try-catch` block catching the `ActivityNotFoundException` (I'm sure that most of the handsets won't have that specific app).

Comment: Thank for the quick response, Cristian. Let me check it out.

Comment: @Cristian: Please tell me how to show a page fit in window in DroidReader? Do I have to pass the extras? I've already posted the question, but no reply yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720443/passing-extras-to-droidreader

Comment: You will have better luck if you ask the DroidReader authors directly. Maybe they even didn't put anything like that and you are wasting your time.

Comment: Hey Cristian, do ya know any other PDF viewer which supports this feature?

Comment: Note -- please see my answer below.  This is *not* a good suggestion, since it ties you to implementation details of the target app that could change at any time and break your code.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend not specifying an explicit class name in the Intent as the accepted answer recommends, since that is an implementation detail of the app that can change at any time on you.

Instead, build your Intent like normal, but use Intent.setPackage() to specify the system should only look in the desired app's package name for matching activities.  That is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriToView);
intent.setPackage("com.package.name.of.droidreader");
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: But this will also bind me to that specific package.

Comment: Yes, but the package name won't change between versions, but the Activity name (i.e. an implementation detail) might.